# Error Code: ForbiddenException http status: Unable to access KeyVault resource with given credentials

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-keyvault

I am trying to implement the Azure Verifiable Credentials demo https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/verifiable-credentials-configure-tenant, however, already after scanning the QR generated in the demo app, which I registered in my Azure Active Directory, I get that I do not have access to the KeyVault resource, when I enabled all access permissions.

Does anyone have any idea what could be generating this error?

[Verifiable Credentials Expert Issuance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6U9v.jpg)
[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKOw0.jpg)

Comment: There's a Note here, did you folllow through and set the right permissions on the Key Vault? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/verifiable-credentials-configure-tenant#create-a-key-vault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In KeyVault add an Access Policy for service principal "Verifiable Credentials Service Request" and give it Key Permissions Get, Sign and save that policy

Comment: This solution helped me, thanks!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/881732/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To resolve **403 Forbidden** error, please check whether you have given required permissions.

Make sure to give permissions like below:

**Key permissions**: *Get, List, Create, Import, Verify and Sign*

**Secret permissions**: *Get, list and Set*

[image]

*Otherwise*, check whether **[firewall policy](https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2019/01/03/key-vault-firewall-access-by-azure-app-services)** is enabled or not.

- If enabled, try adding the **IP address** of your Azure App Service to the Key Vault to make it work.

To know the exact reason behind the error try turning on [**Azure Key Vault logging**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/logging) that will give you the reason behind the error.

Please **refer** below links for more information:

[REST API error codes - Azure Key Vault | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rest-error-codes#http-403-insufficient-permissions)

[Issue your own Verifiable Credentials | Decentralized Identity Developer Docs (didproject.azurewebsites.net)](https://didproject.azurewebsites.net/docs/issuer-setup.html)